# Fixing a messed up branch history

Tags: git, merge

To all the Git experts out there,

currently I have some trouble merging back a long-lived feature-branch. Doing so, Git undoes many changes made to the master-branch over the last year. Since I am quite new to this project and all former employees are gone, I did some research on what went wrong in the Git history. Here is the simplified history of our project:

```
         o---.....---o---...---D             (Feature-Branch)
        /           /           \
---o---A---.....---B---.......---C---o       (Master-Branch)
```

In the project history I can see that the commit "B" is merged into the feature-branch. However, in this merge-commit, the changes from commit "B" seem to be discarded and some other changes are made instead. But no real merge is done. When I try to merge commit "D" back into the master-branch, Git does a 3-way-merge with the common ancestor "B". So comparing commit "C" and "D" to commit "B" only in commit "D" changes are made. Git correctly uses these changes for the resulting merge-commit.

Right now, I have no idea how to solve this "merge conflict". As far as I know, it is not possible to force Git to choose a common ancestor of my choice. Also reverting all flawed merge commits is not really an option, since there are quite a lot.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this without picking all the correct changes by hand?

Comment: Well.... you _could_ make git do what you like with a few tricks. What would you like your "common ancestor"  to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the common ancestor... say you would like A to be the forced common ancestor. You can do this:

```
git checkout --detach D
git reset --soft A
git commit -m "new D"
git merge C
```

That would do. If you don't mind losing the original history of D, you can keep it like this (after you finish the merge). If you want to keep the original history of D, then you would do this (after finishing the merge)

```
git commit-tree -p D -p C -m "blahblah" HEAD^{tree}
```

That will output an ID, create a branch using that ID and there you have your merge revision.